# On submit, gather text from inputs and display it in a separate textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, email-templates

Project: An editable HTML email template

Goal: Create a user friendly set of inputs that, upon form submission, gathers the inputted text and inserts it between specified p tags. The code that makes the email template is in a textarea at the bottom of the page, from which the user can copy the HTML and paste it into an email without having to go into the HTML to make changes. Each input in the form has an ID, as do their respective tags in the HTML where I want the inputted text to appear

Here is the form:

```
<body>
<div id="content"> 
<div id="field">
    <form id="myForm" action="">
        <h2> Header </h2>
        <textarea id="header" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea> 
        <h2>Draft Details </h2>
        <textarea id="draft" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>  
        <h2>Event 1 Image (left)</h2>
        <input id="ev1Img" type="file">
        <h2>Event 1 Details </h2>
        <textarea id="ev1Det" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
        <h2>Event 2 Image (right)</h2>
        <input id="ev2Img" type="file">
        <h2>Event 2 Details</h2>
        <textarea id="ev2Det" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Generate Email Code</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

The text area at the bottom (which contains the HTML template) has p tags with their own IDs:

```
 <p id="Xheader"></p> ...etc
```

I am trying to use Javascript and Jquery to grab the input data and populate my p tags in the HTML:

```
    <script> 

       var dataY = document.getElementById("header", "draft", "ev1Det", "ev2Det").text();
       var dataX = document.getElementById("Xheader", "Xdraft", "Xev1Det","Xev2Det").text();
       document.ready(function() {
          document.getElementById("button").click(function() {
            dataX.text() = dataY.text();
          });
       });

    </script>
```

What are some solutions to make this work? Am I on the right track? I'm sure my JS/ JQ is where the problem is

Comment: What's the problem? Please include actual vs. expected behavior, JS console logs, etc.

Comment: The code has several problem including: wrong usage of jQuery, trying to select multiple IDs or doing the selection outside of any method (likely these elements don't exist when you call it). So ... all wrong I would say :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a `function` called `write`, which expects an `id` and a `text`. I will assume that you already know how to implement that and that you have meant `textarea` when you mentioned `input`.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    $(this).find("textarea").each(function() {
        write($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
    });
});
```

The first line creates a `submit` handler for your `form`, the second iterates the `textarea` elements inside the `form` and the third calls `write` for `textarea` elements. Note, that if you do not define `name`s for your `form` elements, they will not be submitted to the server upon `submit` and note that when you are working with javascript, `this` refers to the `function` you are in.